# Link redirection not working

Tags: php, html

Firstly, have a look a this examle

[See here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html?a=b&pak=thisss#h-12.1)

As given in the example, i want to create a similar page within Telrik Text Editor, i.e List of some link and their corresponding paragraphs.

This is the HTML i m using in Telrik Text Editor, Link are Like This

```
This is the First <a href="#first" class="TableHead">link</a>.
This is the 2nd <a href="#second" class="TableHead">link</a>.
This is the 3rd <a href="#third" class="TableHead">link</a>.
```

And Paragraphs are like this

```
  <a name="first" class="TableHead">1</a>.
  <p>First Para</p>
  <a name="second" class="TableHead">2</a>.
  <p>2nd Para</p>
  <a name="third" class="TableHead">3</a>.
  <p>3rd Para</p>
```

As i understood, a simple HTML page add anchor href at the end of the url.

But my problem is my current page URL is like this

```
http://testdev.com/#/document/document-view?id=c118a6b9-ed7f-410a-9729-341333fb8655
```

This URL already have "#" in it.

Moreover when i clicked on "First" link it redirect to following

```
http://testdev.com/#first
```

I m not sure, but I think this is because of having already one "#" in URL

Please advice some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two anchors in your URL.

One solution is to use javascript function `window.scrollTo`: see http://jsfiddle.net/cujdju5f/

Comment: but content is added by client using editor, and they mostly copy paste HTML so these onclick events will not be there...

Answer (score 1):

True it's correct that it redirect to `http://testdev.com/#first`. Because you are already on the same page `http://testdev.com/` it doesn't reload the page but it will scroll to the `id` that you defined after `#`.

So your current page is: `http://testdev.com/#/document/document-view?id=c118a6b9-ed7f-410a-9729-341333fb8655` where the current page is `http://testdev.com/` and the defined id `/document/document-view?id=c118a6b9-ed7f-410a-9729-341333fb8655`

If you redirect to `http://testdev.com/#first` the page is `http://testdev.com/` and the id is `first`.

So it doesn't redirect the page but goes to the `id` on the same page.

Change your paragraphs HTML into the HTML below and it will work.

```
<a id="first" name="first" class="TableHead">1</a>.
<p>First Para</p>
<a id="second" name="second" class="TableHead">2</a>.
<p>2nd Para</p>
<a id="third" name="third" class="TableHead">3</a>.
<p>3rd Para</p>
```

Comment: BTW: `name` was the old HTML4 way to address an element via the URL anchor. This method is outdated and shouldn't be used anymore. An `id` is all you need and in fact this should be the only use case for IDs in HTML…

Comment: i changed attribute "name" to "id" but it still redirecting to http://testdev.com/#first

Comment: If you use `<a href="#first" class="TableHead">link</a>` as link and `<a id="first" class="TableHead">1</a>` it should work. If it doesn't then maybe it's something else that is troubling.